# VB 2012 error message

Tags: vb.net

I get the following error: Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.   :

in the following line of code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users(userid, passWord, firstName, lastName, jobTitle, SSN) VALUES (" & Me.adduseridtxtbox & ",'" & Me.addpasswordtxt & ",'" & Me.addfirstnametxt & ",'" & Me.addlastnametxt & ",'" & Me.jobcbox & ",'" & Me.addssntxt & "')"
```

here is the code :

```
Private Sub addbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addbtn.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    If Not connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        connection.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = connection
    ' add data to table 
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users(userid, passWord, firstName, lastName, jobTitle, SSN) VALUES (" & Me.adduseridtxtbox & ",'" & Me.addpasswordtxt & ",'" & Me.addfirstnametxt & ",'" & Me.addlastnametxt & ",'" & Me.jobcbox & ",'" & Me.addssntxt & "')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'refresh data in list
    'close connection
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: It is telling you that a TextBox is not a string, you need to use the TextBox's Text Property. ie. `Me.addpasswordtxt.Text`

Comment: A `TextBox` is not a string, so you can't concatenate it like it was. Use the `TextBox.Text` property.

Comment: Two really good answers, one with code you have put to use in your code.  You should accept that answer (click the checkmark) to move this off the unanswered list and show you participate in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Me.adduseridtxtbox.Text` (which gets the value of the `TextBox`) rather than the `TextBox` directly.

Also, please, *please*, ***please*** read about [`OleDbParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) and how to use these parameters with `OleDbCommand` to prevent injection. Microsoft even provides examples.

Currently your code is extremely dangerous if you are letting users fill this form out themselves, as they have full control over your database. Regardless, using `OleDbParameter` is a good practice to get into. You appear to be handling *social security numbers* here -- your users deserve some form of security.

Comment: Thanks for the info..will help me out greatly...as for the ssn...they are fictitious...but I will make the adjustments you (all) recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use/declare parameters in your query.
For example:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO users(userid, passWord, firstName, lastName, jobTitle, SSN) " & _ 
                   "VALUES (@uid, @pw, @fn, @ln, @job, @ssn)")
With cmd.Parameters
.Clear()
.AddWithValue("uid", adduseridtxtbox.Text)
.AddWithValue("uid", adduseridtxtbox.Text)
.AddWithValue("pw", addpasswordtxt.Text
.AddWithValue("fn", addfirstnametxt.Text)
.AddWithValue("ln", addlastnametxt.Text)
.AddWithValue("job",jobcbox.SelectedValue)
.AddWithValue("ssn", addssntxt.Text)
End With
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Also, what if the user table in the database has an auto generated number. Does that need to be figured into the code? If so how?

Comment: If one of your column is an auto generated number, you don't need to include that on your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Statement is not proper. How do you use an object as a string? It should be
`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users(userid, passWord, firstName, lastName, jobTitle, SSN) VALUES ('" & Me.adduseridtxtbox.Text & ",'" & Me.addpasswordtxt.Text & ",'" & Me.addfirstnametxt.Text & ",'" & Me.addlastnametxt.Text & ",'" & Me.jobcbox.Text & ",'" & Me.addssntxt.Text & "')"`

Use parametrised query to prevent SQL Injections and make safe your database system from malicious users.